# Python и комплексный числа с рациональными действительной и мнимой частями

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

В Python есть встроенный модуль поддерживающий точные вычисления с рациональными числами:

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(2, 3) + Fraction(5, 7))
```

Все здорово, если учитывать, что питон по умолчанию использует длинную арифметику.

Мне недавно понадобилось использовать комплексные числа только с рациональными мнимой и действительной частями. Вот что из этого вышло:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> print(Fraction(2, 3) + Fraction(5, 7) * 1j)
(0.6666666666666666+0.7142857142857143j)
>>> print(complex(Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(5, 7)))
(0.6666666666666666+0.7142857142857143j)
```

`Fraction` автоматически приводится к `float`. Как решить проблему?

В C++, например, можно было бы сделать следующим образом:

```
complex<Fraction> z(Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(5, 7));
```

Нельзя ли нечто подобное сделать в Python?

Я пока, что вижу только одно решение написать свой класс Complex, но надеюсь есть решение проще.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Боюсь, что другого способа действительно нет.

Единственное что, хорошим тоном будет наследоваться от абстрактного класса Complex https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/numbers.html. Это не даст упустить какие-то важные методы и в итоге позволит сделать класс с интерфейсом идентичным оригинальному.